# Approximately how many Jews would make the pilgrimage for aliyas l'regel during its height? How large of a gathering was it?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, israel

I've seen some writers talk about the rally in D.C. being the largest single gathering of Jews since Sinai.  I would think that is not accurate in that, at the very least, we may have had greater numbers during the first beis hamikdash period for aliyas l'regel. Appreciate any responses and sources.

Comment: Well, [many people apparently](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/135534/759) believe there were twice as many Jews as the DC rally on a street in Jerusalem way back when every single day.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Michoel and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: My Rav told me Josephus recorded one year that he saw 3 million people giving the korban pesach

Comment: At the least, funerals of Rabbis in Jerusalem and Bnei Berak in the past decade have had >500K

Comment: @ AKA, good point about the levayas.