What major international cities, with a significant Jewish presence, lack any eruv?
When I visited Rome this year I was aware that it had no kosher eruv in the Jewish area.  Many observant Jewish tourists seemed unaware of the Shabbos prohibitions when there is no eruv, and used strollers, etc., in violation of Halacha.  This problem is not limited to European capitals, but even large areas of New York have no eruv (and the crowded city is considered by most poskim to be incapable of having an eruv).  Can anyone list tourist/business destinations where one should assume there is no eruv anywhere in the metropolis?

Paris has none in large parts of the city, maybe all of it, same for London, I think the question is reverse. What is the short list of cities in Europe with an eruv?

And Asia, Dubai?

@mbloch historically eruvin were generally only found in the few streets of Jewish ghettos. Only in the last 150 years did people try putting up giant metropolitan ones (in violation of established halacha in many cases that large urban areas are too populous for an eruv https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/135537/759 )

Recently visited Zurich- no Eruv there

I may be misremembering, but I vaguely recall that when I was in Krakow for Shabbat a decade ago there wasn't an Eruv.

Yeah, Rabbi Charlop zt'l has a shiur about major sea changes in halacha in the 20th Century, and this is one of them -- eruvin in big parts of big cities; it's a new thing. (Someone in Chicago described their story there as "basically we kept waiting for Rabbi Aaron Soloveitchik to die, but then gave up on waiting and starting building the eruv anyhow.")

Gateshead, UK, last time I checked
